# Google Analytics and iTunes Analytics Sessions differences

Tags: ios, session, google-analytics, app-store-connect

We have different values for Apple and Google Sessions statistics, I found such information:

**Apple:**
Sessions counts the number of times the app has been in the foreground for at least two seconds. If the app is in the background and is later used again, that counts as another session.
https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/App%20Analytics_Definitions

**Google:**
By default, Google Analytics will group hits that are received within 30 minutes of one another into the same session. This period is configurable at the property level.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sessions

Do you have any other information about this statistics?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is about Google analytics statistics and is not programing related.